# How to change column datatype str to time in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table in which opening and closing timings are  present as a text in mysql like

[image]

| Open | Close |
| --- | --- |
| 10:30:AM | 05:30:PM |
| 10:30:AM | 07:00:PM |

I need to calculate the total hours of business i.e. how many hours entity opened for that calculation, need to convert it to time format. I tried to update/ alter table but it showing syntax error and also tried to function but it showing error.

Also tried below queries with update/alter but don't get desired output

```
select
    open,
    close,
    str_to_date(open, '%h:%i%a') as formatted_time_open, 
    str_to_date(close, '%h:%i%p') as formatted_time_close 
from
    museum_hours;
```

Comment: *`str_to_date(open, '%h:%i%a')`* Incorrect, it does not take into account the presence of second `:`. Also AM/PM pattern is `%p`. Totally: `str_to_date(open, '%h:%i:%p')`. The same for `close`.